# How to verify if a level is in a list of string, and active a button depending on the level

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a levelSelection scene, where there is 8 button container in a gameObject called "levelPanel".

Each container is named "buttonLevel1" "buttonLevel2" ...

[levelPanel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiNaH.png)

I have a list of string named levelsUnlocked, that is in the gameManager (GameManager.instance.levelsUnlocked).

I have tried a simple list, but it said that I can't `.setActive(false)` a parent gameObject

I tried

```
List<List<GameObject>>[] levelButtons = new List<List<GameObject>>();
```

but it's worse (I think).

I'm new to C#/Unity, so I don't understand why it doesn't want to work (it was working in my head, I got reality check).

Here is my current code, in levelPanel

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class LevelSelectionScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<List<GameObject>>[] levelButtons;

    void Start()
    {
        // Désactiver tous les boutons au début
        foreach(List<GameObject> buttonList in levelButtons)
        {
            foreach(GameObject button in buttonList)
            {
                button.SetActive(false);
            }
        }

        // Activer les boutons des niveaux débloqués
        foreach(string levelName in GameManager.instance.levelsUnlocked)
        {
            if(levelName.StartsWith("Level "))
            {
                int levelNumber;

                if (int.TryParse(levelName.Substring(6), out levelNumber))
                {
                    if (levelNumber >= 1 && levelNumber <= 8)
                    {
                        int buttonIndex = levelNumber - 1;

                        foreach (GameObject button in levelButtons[buttonIndex, 0])
                        {
                            button.SetActive(true);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the error I get:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>
> LevelSelectionScript.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/LevelSelectionScript.cs:13)
>
> Assets\Scripts\LevelSelectionScript.cs(13,9): error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.List<UnityEngine.GameObject>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<UnityEngine.GameObject>'
>
> Assets\Scripts\LevelSelectionScript.cs(32,54): error CS0022: Wrong number of indices inside []; expected 1
>
> Assets\Scripts\LevelSelectionScript.cs(32,25): error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<UnityEngine.GameObject>' to 'UnityEngine.GameObject'

oops, answered in the previous question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one thing that I noticed is that your levelButtons field is three collections deep: an array of lists of lists; it's declared as:

```
List<List<GameObject>>[] levelButtons;
```

My immediate hunch is that if you remove the '[]' (i.e. the array declaration) things may be working as you'd expect.